# C++ Function call with a 'new' array argument

Tags: c++, arrays, argument-passing

I want to call a function which requires an array of integers. How could I do this without creating a new array of integers every time I want to call the function?

This is what I want to do:

```
someFunction(new int[]{obj[0].getInt(), obj[1].getInt()});
```

instead of doing this:

```
int intArray[2] = {obj[0].getInt(), obj[1].getInt()};    
someFunction(intArray);
```

Comment: No, you do *not* want the first example. What's wrong with the second one?

Comment: Erm. What? The first example creates a new array every time you want to call the function.

Comment: You will likely create a memory leak with your first example.

Comment: No the first just throws an error

Comment: I believe if I delete the array in the function called, there won't be a mem leak

Comment: @BobSmith , yes, but killing the given array isn't a side affect you want to have for a class constructor.

Comment: The second way is idiomatic C++. Don't try to make the language something it isn't, especially just to save a line of code.

Comment: @BobSmith, The first is valid in C++11 AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have been coding in java recently and forgot that while this is possible in java, I guess this can't be done in c++.

Comment: You can omit the 2 in the second option btw.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Just deleting an array that the function is just ought to process and thus requiring the caller to always new it is never a side effect you want, constructor or not.

Comment: @BobSmith Preventing memory leaks is not just about spamming `delete`s in order to counter the `new`s spammed without reason in the first place. This is not Java.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can use C++11, you can define `somefunction` to take an `std::vector` (or a `std::vector const &`) instead of an actual array, and then use:

```
somefunction({obj[0].getInt(), obj[1].getInt()});
```

Unlike Java, you do *not* need to use `new` on a regular basis in C++. In fact, in most well written code it's fairly unusual.

As an aside, you generally want to avoid C++'s built-in arrays, and C++11 makes it easier to do that, to the point that there's rarely a good reason to use them at all.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` would probably be much more efficient than `std::vector`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: yes, you could accept an `std::initializer_list` directly, but assuming you want something like an array, an `std::vector` is roughly similar, and has a ctor that itself accepts an `std::initializer_list`...